# Calculate distance to left/right viewport edge on load AND resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, viewport, window-resize

I am trying to calculate the distance of an element to the left (and in another case to the right) edge of the viewport, so I could add it as a negative margin for the element to align with the viewport's edge. So far it works on load, but does some strange calculations when resizing the browser. Do I think something wrong here?
Here's what I use so far:

Right-viewport alignment:

```
$sidepic_element = jQuery('.right_element');

if($sidepic_element.length) {
    jQuery(window).on("load resize", function() {
        $offset = $sidepic_element.offset();
        $sidepic_margin = -(jQuery(window).width() - ($sidepic_element.offset().left + $sidepic_element.width()));
        $sidepic_element.css({
            'margin-right': $sidepic_margin
        });
    });
}
```

Left-viewport alignment:

```
$blog_element = jQuery('.left_element');

jQuery(window).on("load resize", function() {
    $offset = $blog_element.offset();
    $blog_margin = -($blog_element.offset().left - jQuery(window).scrollLeft());
    $blog_element.css({
        'margin-left': $blog_margin
    });
});
```